# Create a new Rectangle next to other object Location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, I want to instantly create a new rectangle next to a picturebox. Imagine that I write that the Rectangle Location equals to PictureBox1 Location plus x+10. How to do that in C#?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new Rectangle by using its constructor [Rectangle(int,int,int,int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wcdy991.aspx) that specify x,y,width and height.
So use previous Rectangle's x+10,y,width,height as parameters.

```
Rectangle newRect = new Rectangle(
  pictureBox1.Location.X + 10, 
  pictureBox1.Location.Y, 
  pictureBox1.Width, 
  pictureBox1.Heigth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Did it from the top of my head so you might have a few misnamed properties.

```
 Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), 1);
 e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(
    blackPen, 
    pictureBox1.Location.X + 10, 
    pictureBox1.Location.Y, 
    pictureBox1.Size.Width, 
    pictureBox1.Size.Heigth);
```

(JustGoogleIt)